# Estimating $p$ from $A1$ and $A1$, system of equations, an estimation problem

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, estimation

Does anyone here know how $\rho$ is estimated in terms of $A_1, A_2 $ in the below equations, any mathematical procedure for this ..

$$ A_1 =  \left |  \alpha\; \left(\frac{ 1- e^{-j\cdot 2\cdot\pi \rho}}{j2\pi \rho}\right)  \right|^2   $$

$$ A_2 = \left |\alpha\; \left(\frac{ 1- e^{-j\cdot 2\cdot\pi \rho}}{j2\pi+j2\pi \rho}\right) \right|^2   $$
$$ \rho=\frac{A_2+\sqrt(A_1A_2)}{A_1-A_2}  $$

I am working on an estimation problem where from $A_1 , A_2 $ they estimated $p$ that is inside $A1$ and $A2$.

Anyone who could tell me about any mathematical procedure that how they did so?

Comment: Divide $(1)$ by $(2)$ but the problem is that you get $\rho=\frac {A_2}{A_1-A_2}$. Are you sure of the equations ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I am reading a paper in which A1 is actually the absolute square of the first equation and A2 is the absolute square of the second equation however the symbol of the absolute square was a typo. So 

equation -1 is actually the absolute square of A1 and equation 2 is the absolute square of A2. I

Comment: Please, edit your post accordingly.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I am doing it, thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Can you see the new question I posted now, it's the same 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3998864/extracting-estimating-lambda-from-any-two-equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you wrote in comments
$$\frac{A_1}{A_2}=\frac{(\rho +1)^2}{\rho ^2}$$ which is a quadratic in $\rho$.

Solve it and select the root you need.

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved it and it is 100% right.

Comment: I have one more question that I posted, can you look into that too? math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993813/… – good_omen92