# Estimating Zeta from Hv and Hu , system of equations, estimation problem

Tags: linear-algebra, estimation

Does anyone here know how $\beta$ could be estimated in terms of $H_u, H_v $ in the below equations,

$$ H_u =  \left |  \zeta\; \left(\frac{ e^{-j\cdot 2\cdot\pi}-e^{-j\cdot 2\cdot\pi(1/T)(T-\Delta t)}}{j2\pi}\right)-\zeta-\beta  \right|^2   $$

$$ H_v = \left |  \zeta\; \left(\frac{ e^{j\cdot 2\cdot\pi}-e^{j\cdot 2\cdot\pi(1/T)(\Delta t)}}{j2\pi}\right)+\zeta\beta  \right|^2   $$

This is absolute sqauare of $H_v$ and $H_u$

I am working on an estimation problem where from $H_u , H_v $ they estimated $\beta$ that is inside $H_u$ and $H_v$.

**Anyone who could tell me about any mathematical procedure that how I can we do so?**

A previous example where we did so... Almost same problem

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3984685/estimating-p-from-a1-and-a1-system-of-equations-an-estimation-problem/3984708#3984708

$$ A_1 =  \left |  \alpha\; \left(\frac{ 1- e^{-j\cdot 2\cdot\pi \rho}}{j2\pi \rho}\right)  \right|^2   $$

$$ A_2 = \left |\alpha\; \left(\frac{ 1- e^{-j\cdot 2\cdot\pi \rho}}{j2\pi+j2\pi \rho}\right) \right|^2   $$
$$ \rho=\frac{A_2+\sqrt(A_1A_2)}{A_1-A_2}  $$

divided $A_1$ by $A_2$ equations

A1A2=(ρ+1)2ρ2

which is a quadratic in ρ.

I Solved it and select the root you I needed. I found $\rho $ in terms of $A_1, A_2 $