# Extracting/ Estimating Lambda from H1 and H2.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations, estimation

Aficionados, Does anyone here know how to extract $\lambda$ from below of $H_1, H_2 $ in these equations in terms of $H_1$ and $H_2$

$$ H_1 =  \left |  P.\zeta\; \left(\frac{ e^{j\cdot 2\cdot\pi}-e^{j\cdot 2\cdot\pi\lambda}}{j2\pi/T}\right) + P.\zeta\delta  \right|^2   $$

$$ H_2 = \left | - P.\zeta\; \left(\frac{ e^{-j\cdot 2\cdot\pi}-e^{-j\cdot 2\cdot\pi\lambda}}{j2\pi/T}\right) + P.\zeta\delta t \right|^2   $$

This is absolute sqauare of $H_1$ and $H_2$

A few manipulations could help me.

In our previous problem, we estimated p where from $A_1$ , $A_2$

**Anyone who could tell me about any mathematical procedure that how I can we do so?**

A previous example where we did so... Almost same problem

[Estimating $p$ from $A1$ and $A1$, system of equations, an estimation problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3984685/estimating-p-from-a1-and-a1-system-of-equations-an-estimation-problem/3984708#3984708)

$$ A_1 =  \left |  \alpha\; \left(\frac{ 1- e^{-j\cdot 2\cdot\pi \rho}}{j2\pi \rho}\right)  \right|^2   $$

$$ A_2 = \left |\alpha\; \left(\frac{ 1- e^{-j\cdot 2\cdot\pi \rho}}{j2\pi+j2\pi \rho}\right) \right|^2   $$
$$ \rho=\frac{A_2+\sqrt(A_1A_2)}{A_1-A_2}  $$

divided $A_1$ by $A_2$ equations

A1A2=(ρ+1)2ρ2

which is quadratic in ρ.

I Solved it and select the root you I needed. I found $\rho $ in terms of $A_1, A_2 $

**If you guys wanted to do it without considering absolute square even then it will help me** Like this

$$ H_1 =    P.\zeta\; \left(\frac{ e^{j\cdot 2\cdot\pi}-e^{j\cdot 2\cdot\pi\lambda}}{j2\pi/T}\right) + P.\zeta\delta    $$

$$ H_2 =  - P.\zeta\; \left(\frac{ e^{-j\cdot 2\cdot\pi}-e^{-j\cdot 2\cdot\pi\lambda}}{j2\pi/T}\right) + P.\zeta\delta t   $$